# Carriage returns appear for no apparent reason in Sharepoint's task description field

Tags: tasks, task-list

I use Sharepoint's task description field as a log for my team's project status updates. I'll enter in a line by sometimes typing it and sometimes copy pasting something from an email.  Later, when I go back to edit or add something else, a bunch of carriage returns have appeared in the description field adding a ton of annoying blank space to the description field.  What causes this?

Answer (score 0):

Description field on the Task list is of type multi line of text and by default it is set to allow `Enhanced rich text (Rich text with pictures, tables, and hyperlinks)` which is why you are getting Carriage returns in your text. [image]

**Option 1:**

you can change it to plain text if you don't need Rich text

**Option 2:**

When you enter text that has these characters, you can manually remove them, by clicking on Format Text (from the Ribbon) and click on Edit Source and remove the extra characters you don't like!